# Querying JSON column in MySQL with id

Tags: mysql, json

I have a table in MySQL with data in a column in the following format:

```
[{"type_id":1,"price":50},{"type_id":3,"price":60}]
```

I need to find out price of the item based on its id. For example, I need to find out price of an item with type_id = 3

I have tried:

```
select JSON_EXTRACT(JSONColumn, '$[*].price') as prices, JSON_EXTRACT(JSONColumn, '$[*].type_id') as quantities from Items where ItemId = 123
and json_contains(JSONColumn, '{"type_id" : 3}')
```

This is not working. Can someone specify the correct way of querying json data?

Comment: The problem you are having is that your data format is not correct, there may bi a way to do it which I am not aware of but the correct way to do it would be to create a new table with two columns and relate it to the current one. Then with a simple "join" and "where" you have your data

Comment: That is the correct way but unfortunately I need to do it with the existing table structure as it is a legacy application working with this schema. Introducing new tables and migrating existing data is going to be a lengthy task than finding a way to query existing JSON.

Comment: Then I am sorry but I cannot help you in sql, What I would do is do  is get the whole list of objects and treat it in js php or the language you are using, it's really inefficient but it may work if you don't have huge JSONs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT test.id, jsontable.price
FROM test
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE (test.val,
                       '$[*]' COLUMNS (type_id INT PATH '$.type_id',
                                       price INT PATH '$.price')) jsontable
WHERE jsontable.type_id = 3;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=baa0a24a4bbf10ba30202c7156720018